# how to pass a function to re.findall() in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a list of words that I want to search in a string of large text.I have defined a function that returns each individual word but I dont know how to pass the function to re.findall(). I want to get any sentense that contains any word that is in words list.
Can someone assist :)
here is what I got:

```
strings = ['some large text', 'some large text'...]
ad = []
words = ['ascertained','deep','detected','disclosed','disinterred','espied','explored','exposed','famous','happened upon','identified','invented','learned','observed','perceived','presented','revealed','searched out','shown','sighted','spotted','unveiled']
def word():
    for i in words:
        t = word[i]
    return t

for i in range(len(strings)):
    ad += re.findall(r"([^.]*?word()[^.]*\.)",strings[i])
sep = ''
adc = sep.join(ad)
```

Comment: Could you explain in detail, and with examples, what sentences you want to match and how. Your current code doesn't make any sense

Comment: `t = word[i]` <--- something is wrong here

Comment: I don't know what are you doing and why do you need that. But straight away the  answer is something like this: `ad += re.findall(f"([^.]*?{word()}[^.]*\.)",strings[i])
`

Comment: for example: lets say strings = ['my name is D.', 'I am 18 years old', 'I love deep learning']    re.findall() should return 'I love deep learning '  b,cause it has the word deep which is defined in the words list. Isn't that not clear enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this:

```
strings = ['some large text', 'some large text', 'dont disclosed it']
words = ['ascertained','deep','detected','disclosed','disinterred','espied','explored','exposed','famous','happened upon','identified','invented','learned','observed','perceived','presented','revealed','searched out','shown','sighted','spotted','unveiled']
```

---

```
reg = re.compile("(?=(" + "|".join(map(re.escape, words)) + "))")
ad = [i for i in strings if len(re.findall(reg,i))]
ad = ', '.join(ad)
```

---

**ad:**

```
'dont disclosed it'
```

---

### OR

```
strings = ['my name is D.', 'I am 18 years old', 'I love deep learning', 'detected something fishy'] 
ad = []
words = ['ascertained','deep','detected','disclosed','disinterred','espied','explored','exposed','famous','happened upon','identified','invented','learned','observed','perceived','presented','revealed','searched out','shown','sighted','spotted','unveiled']

for i in range(len(strings)):
    ad += [strings[i] for word in words if len(re.findall(f"([^.]*?{word}[^.]*)", strings[i]))]
```

**Output:**

**ad:**

```
['I love deep learning', 'detected something fishy']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(strings)):
    ad += [re.findall(f"([^.]*?{word}[^.]*\.)", strings[i]) for word in words]
```